# Types of types of numbers

Tags: soft-question, terminology

What is the distinction between descriptors for numbers such as rational, algebraic, and real, and descriptors such as cardinal and ordinal?

The words real, complex, etc. describe the properties of numbers, e.g., natural numbers follow the Peano axioms, integers are natural numbers with additive inverse, rationals integers with multiplicative inverse, and so forth. Even words that describe numbers without a group-like structure, such as primes or Fibonacci numbers.

But the terms cardinal numbers and ordinal numbers feel different, like numbers that serve a certain purpose but don't have some sort of additional structure imposed on them, not 'truly numbers'. Like they weren't made to be 'added', even though things like $\omega+\omega$ and $2^{\beth_0}$ have valid meaning. I'm not sure how to describe how I feel about these numbers, but are they of a different kind than the numbers named in the previous paragraph? What are other examples of descriptors of numbers of this type?

My feeling is that it's similar to the difference between sets and proper classes.

Comment: See e.g [whats-the-difference-between-cardinal-and-ordinal-as-adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/whats-the-difference-between-cardinal-and-ordinal-as-adjectives) as well as [Cardinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) and [Ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).

Comment: Both are "generalizations" of the *natural numbers*, i.e. the number used "to count": Cardinal for "describing" the how many objects we have in a bag and Ordinal to "describe" how objects are ordered in a row.

Comment: Ordinals are very specific *sets:* those that are transitive and well-ordered by $\in$. (And, depending on the author, cardinals may be specific ordinals). On the other hand, a natural number, a complex number, etc. is usually not considered as a set; but they can be *modeled* as sets (e.g., the natural number $n$ by the unique ordinal of cardiality $n$, and the set $\Bbb N$ of all natural numbers is than simply the first infinite ordinal $\omega$), but these models are not unique (i.e., not specific) and it is often best to simply consider numbers as "urelements"